# Facebook Graph API and koala: How to find places in a city

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, location, koala

Using a Rails app with koala, how can I get a list of restaurants and places within a city?

For reference:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@current_user.oauth_token)
graph.get_object("me")["location"]["name"]
```

gets me the user's city.

Answer (score 0):

To use Graph API Search with Koala Gem create an object and use `.graph-call` method and pass in the api call you would make as a single string parameter like so:

```
fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(ENV['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_TOKEN'])
lookup = fb.graph_call("search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000")
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the specifics of the Koala framework, but Graph API-wise you can use the search endpoint es described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Sample query:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/search?
    q=coffee&
    type=place&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```

Also have a look at

- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/arsduo/koala/Koala/Facebook/GraphAPIMethods:search