# how to search for pages with koala

Tags: ruby, facebook, koala, koala-gem

I'm trying to using Koala gem to search for facebook page, like this

```
@graph.get_connection('search', movie_name)
```

but I got this `/Users/luizeduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:1100:in rescue in merge': bad URI(is not URI?): /search/Jurassic World (URI::InvalidURIError)`

Seems like I'm using the wrong method OR this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API#getting-private-data

> You can also search for users/pages/events/groups for the keyword of your choice:

```
# http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=koala&type=place
@graph.get_connection('search', type: :place)
# => [{"category"=>"Attractions/things to do", ...
#     "name"=>"Maru Koala & Animal Park"}]}
```

In your case this would mean

```
@graph.get_connection('search', type: :page)
```

IMHO...

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

Comment: worked with `graph.search(movie_name, type: 'page')` actually but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

get_connection throws the same error for me as well (maybe because v2.6?).

anyway, i found that solution works:

```
@graph.get_object('search?q=YOUR_QUERY&type=page')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're use of `get_connection` seems like the incorrect method for doing a general search of public page data.  `get_connection` has more to do with FB friends network.  For a more detailed understanding of what API calls Koala will make, have a look at the code which has good comments describing how each method works.  For general API graph calls you can simply use the `graph_call` method.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb

You should be able to use the `graph_call` method and pass in whatever api call you'd like to make as single parameter in a string.

```
fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(ENV['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_TOKEN'])
lookup = fb.graph_call("search?q=star%20wars%20movie&type=page")
```

[see similar question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679956/facebook-graph-api-and-koala-how-to-find-places-in-a-city/36696332)

Answer (score 0):

The [Koala Wiki](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API#getting-private-data) should say this:
`@graph.search('koala', type: :place)`

instead of this:
`@graph.get_connection('search', type: :place)`

Hopefully that gets you closer to a solution.